# Independence of events and union

Tags: probability

I wanted to prove that if $A$, $B$, $C$ are independent 2 by to 2, $A$ and $B\cup C$ are not always independent, but I failed to build a counter-example. Is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variable distributed uniformly in $\lbrace -1,1\rbrace$ and let $Z=XY$. Let also $\Omega$ be the set of these $4$ possibilities, then you get a counter example using $A=\lbrace \omega\in\Omega | X(\omega)=-1\rbrace$, $B=\lbrace \omega\in\Omega | Y(\omega)=-1\rbrace$ and $C=\lbrace \omega\in\Omega | Z(\omega)=-1\rbrace$.

The events $A$, $B$ and $C$ are pairwise independents but clearly, the event $(B\cup C)^c$ and $A$ are disjoints, so $B\cup C$ and $A$ cannot be independents.

Answer (score 1):

I assume A,B and C are events .

Let X, Y and Z be binary random variables .Consider Y and Z independent RV and
$P(Y=0)=P(Y=1)=P(Z=0)=P(Z=1) = \frac{1}{2} $ . Define X = Y xor Z ("xor" mean exclusive or - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) . Define events A = "X=1", B = "Y=1" and C = "Z=1" .

It's easy to check that :

\begin{equation}
P(A,B) = P(X=1,Y=1) = P(Y=1)P(Z=0) = \frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{2} =\frac{1}{4}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
P(A) = P(X=1) = \frac{1}{2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
P(B) = P(Y=1) = \frac{1}{2}
\end{equation}

So we have that P(A,B) = P(A)P(B) , so A and B are independent . Analogically can be shown that A and C are independent and A and B are independent by construction.

Now let's check the independence of A and $B \cup C$ .

\begin{equation}
P(A, B \cup C) = P(X=1, Y=1 or Z=1) = P(Y=1 or Z=1|X=1)P(X=1) = 1*\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
P(A) = \frac{1}{2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
P(B \cup C) = P(Z=1) + P(Y=1) - P(Z=1 and Y=1) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4} = \frac{3}{4}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
P(A)P(B \cup C) = \frac{3}{8}
\end{equation}